# Best way to create user profile with multiple attributes in python?

Tags: python, udp, protocols

I am writing a user profile for a python script to run, which includes the user name, date of birth and their ip address. There will be multiple users, am I on the right track? Or do I use a list/array to replace it?

```
import datetime
from mimetypes import init

class member:
  def __init__(member, name, dob, ip):
    member.name = "John"
    member.dob = datetime.datetime(1989, 10, 20)
    member.ip = "192.168.0.1"
  def __init__(terry, name, dob, ip):
    terry.name = "Terry"
    terry.dob = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 23)
    terry.ip = "192.168.0.2"
  def __init__(andrew, name, dob, ip):
    andrew.name = "Andrew"
    andrew.dob = datetime.datetime(2001, 8, 3)
    andrew.ip = "192.168.0.3"
  def __init__(adrian, name, dob, ip):
    adrian.name = "Adrian"
    adrian.dob = datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 20)
    adrian.ip = "192.168.0.4"
```

The code will be imported to the udp send script to send a message when the date match.

```
import os
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from member import member

#TODO
#add time and condition on date match to send to specific ip for each member
if member.dob.month & member.dob.day == datetime.datetime.now():
    MESSAGE = "Happy birthday to you!" + member.name
    print(MESSAGE)
else:
    pass


UDP_IP = member.ip
UDP_PORT = 5005
#MESSAGE = "Happy birthday to you!"

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: you have to learn OOP because your class memeber is totally wrong. Class should have only one `__init__` and it should get values as parameters but you have it hardcoded. Better use normal list with dictionares.

Comment: if you want to use class `memeber` then it would have to also use `list` to keep all profiles. And in both situations (class or normal list) you will need `for`-loop to check every profile on list.

Comment: `if (member.dob.month == datetime.datetime.now().month) and (member.dob.day == datetime.datetime.now().day):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep it as normal list with dictionares

```py
import datetime

members = [
    {
        'name': "John",
        'dob': datetime.datetime(1989, 10, 20),
        'ip': "192.168.0.1",
    },
    {
        'name': "Terry",
        'dob': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 23),
        'ip': "192.168.0.2",
    },
    {
        'name': "Andrew",
        'dob': datetime.datetime(2001, 8, 3),
        'ip': "192.168.0.3",
    },
    {
        'name': "Adrian",
        'dob': datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 20),
        'ip': "192.168.0.4",
    },
    {
        'name': "Other",
        'dob': datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 25),  # today date for test
        'ip': "192.168.0.5",
    },
]
```

and you should use `for`-loop to check every profile

```py
today = datetime.datetime.now()

for profile in members:
    dob = profile['dob']
    if (dob.month == today.month) and (dob.day == today.day):
        print(profile['name'], profile['ip'])
        # ... send message ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you could use `members` to create `pandas.DataFrame` and write in `csv` - so later you could read from `csv` instead of use `members`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(members)
df.to_csv('memebers.csv', index=False)

print(df)
```

and

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('memebers.csv')
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])                 

print(df)

today = datetime.datetime.now()

for index, profile in df.iterrows():
    dob = profile['dob']
    if (dob.month == today.month) and (dob.day == today.day):
        print(profile['name'], profile['ip'])
        # ... send message ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to use class then first you can create class for single profile

```
class Profile:   # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes
    def __init__(self, name, dob, ip):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob
        self.ip = ip
```

and next list with all instances

```
members = [
    Profile("John", datetime.datetime(1989, 10, 20), "192.168.0.1"),
    Profile("Terry", datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 23), "192.168.0.2"),
    Profile("Andrew", datetime.datetime(2001, 8, 3), "192.168.0.3"),
    Profile("Adrian", datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 20), "192.168.0.4"),
    Profile("Other", datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 25), "192.168.0.5"), # today date for test
]
```

and later you can use it with `for`-loop but you can use `profile.dob`, `profile.name`, `profile.ip` instead of `profile['dob']`, `profile['name']`, `profile['ip']`

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()

for profile in members:
    if (profile.dob.month == today.month) and (profile.dob.day == today.day):
        print(profile.name, profile.ip)
        # ... send message ...
```